# Confirm the Page is loaded or not

Tags: java, selenium

i have list of Hyperlinks in one page, when i click the links , they are redirecting to the new tab. how do i find out whether the page is loaded or not. i have used the do while loop for find out the element is enabled or not. but i am getting "no such element" only. could you please help on this.. Below is the piece of code. i have tried with Explicit wait also . but getting the same issue.

```
    WebElement element7 = driver.findElement(By.id("MenuControlBNY_MenuNavBar_MenuControlBNY_MenuNavBar_p11__Tree_item_2_cell"));
    if (element7.isEnabled())
    {
        element7.click();
        System.out.println(" Report is selected");
    }

    boolean element8 = false;
    int count = 0 ;
    do
    {
        element8 = driver.findElement(By.id("working")).isEnabled();
        System.out.println("Report is loaded");
        count = count+1;
        if(count == 1000)
        {
            break;
        }
    }while(element8 == true);
```

Comment: One of colleague has suggested need to use event Lister functions. Please suggest and help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following, its fairly self explanatory.

```
private static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
private static JavascriptExecutor js  = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

public static void waitForPageLoaded() {
            wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    Boolean res = (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
                    System.out.println("[DEBUG] waitForPageLoaded: " + res);
                    return res;
            }
    });
}
```

EDIT: This will return true when the page is in a ready state ie the page is loaded. So you would call the above method prior to searching for your element.

Comment: I'm open to correction on this, but i don't believe there are any built in methods that specifically wait for the page to load.

Comment: line 59 of the [WebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java#L59) class.  `"method will block until the load is complete"`

Comment: actually, reading more into it, the [WebElement](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.java#L38) class, line 38 states that it most likely doesn't. (using the `WebElement#click()` method)

Comment: While i am pasting the above method , i am getting two errors .

Comment: in the until line is showing the error message as well as the js variable is not initialized in the script

Comment: my bad, should have clarified that you need a new JavaScriptExecutor and WebDriverWait. Have added these to the code above.

Comment: public static WebDriver setUpDriver(String browser)  , i am initialized the browser using the setUpDriver method. if i used your code, the driver column is getting the error in both lines. could you please help on that. Below is my method code

Comment: public static WebDriver setUpDriver(String browser) {
  WebDriver driver = null;
  if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Data\\sw\\IEDriverServer.exe");
   System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.ie.driver"));
   driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  } else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Data\\sw\\chromedriver_win32(2)\\chromedriver.exe");
System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
   driver = new ChromeDriver ();
  }
  return driver;
 }

Comment: i find it very hard to read that. and without knowledge of what the errors actually are, i cant help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76513/discussion-between-krishna-and-cathal).

Answer (score 0):

You can set an implicit wait which will wait for the elements when finding them for a 15 seconds

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or explicitly:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("working")));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided, I am assuming you have clicked the link and the page is opened in a new tab and then you are getting nu such elment exception.

In this case you need to switch to the new tab using window handles and use explict wait for element.here is sample code

```
String parentWindow= driver().getWindowHandle();
element7.click();
Set<String> myset = driver().getWindowHandles();
myset.remove(parentWindow);
driver().switchTo().window((String)myset.toArray()[0]);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(locator)));
```